# Set same attribute on multiple instances of struct without for loop in Rust

Tags: for-loop, rust, struct

I have a `Vec` of `MyStruct` (`Vec<MyStruct>`):

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    attr1: i32,
    ...
}

let mut my_vec = Vec::new();
for _ in 1..100 {
    my_vec.push(MyStruct::new());
}
```

And I need to set the `attr1` to the same value `val1` on all the instances on that `Vec`. What I have right now to do this is:

```rust
let new_attr1 = 42;
for my_str in my_vec.iter_mut() {
    my_str.attr1 = new_attr1;
}
```

Is there a way to do this without a for loop that's more idiomatic?

Comment: Why do you think this `for` loop is not idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without a for loop

Using [`for_each()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) maybe?

```rust
my_vec.iter_mut().for_each(|my_str| my_str.attr1 = new_attr1);
```

> that's more idiomatic

No. In fact, [it's the opposite](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each):

> It's generally more idiomatic to use a `for` loop

Two things to note about this code, however:

- Prefer `for my_str in &mut my_vec` to `for my_str in my_vec.iter_mut()`. In fact, [there's even a Clippy lint for that](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#explicit_iter_loop).
- If you find yourself doing that a lot of times, you can define a macro for it:

```rust
macro_rules! set_all {
    ( $collection:ident . $attr:ident = $value:expr ) => {
        for item in &mut $collection {
            item.$attr = $value;
        }
    };
}

set_all!(my_vec.attr1 = new_attr1);
```

But I doubt this is better.